# Xamarin Forms IOS Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, forms, xamarin, navbar

need help on Xamarin Forms IOS (Android works fine). When I open a new page on a tabbed project, the navbar on IOS appears INVISIBLE, but when scrolling the page up and down, the Navbar appears, although invisible, the back button is there and can be clicked. All other pages of the project have the same behavior, the back button is there, but invisible.  See the image below.
How to set for navbar visible for all pages?

**see GIF here :**

[image: see GIF here]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is default behavior change for iOS15, to solve the issue we just need to modify the `scrollEdgeAppearance` property of `UINavigationBarAppearance`  .

Place the following code in `AppDelegate.cs` or `SceneDelegate.cs` in iOS project .

```
UINavigationBarAppearance a = new UINavigationBarAppearance();
a.ConfigureWithTransparentBackground();
a.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
a.TitleTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes() { ForegroundColor = UIColor.White};


UINavigationBar.Appearance.StandardAppearance = a;
UINavigationBar.Appearance.CompactAppearance = a;
UINavigationBar.Appearance.ScrollEdgeAppearance = a;
```

Refer to

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/684454 .

Comment: If problem has been solved please consider marking it as answer to help others who's facing the same issue .

Comment: Hi Colex, I'm new on stackoverflow. How to mark answer ? Also I have same problem with tabbar is becomes transparent when content is scrolled up.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: thanks man, still don't know why everything is difficult programming this stuff (I just want a background color for a navigation bar?) but this helped a lot! Also if you want a custom color in xamarin then you can do: Color.FromHex("#[hex color]").ToUIColor();